# DNSServerSearchOrder output format

Tags: powershell

Been developing a PowerShell function to display useful information to me.

I am working on making it default to localhost when no parameter is specified or take a command line parameter but that is another version.  The main issue I am trying to resolve is outputting the DNSServerSearchOrder.

Here is my code.

```cs
function Get-CompInf {
    $ComputerName    = "."
    $ComputerSystem  = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName
    $OperatingSystem = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName
    $Bios            = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_BIOS -ComputerName $ComputerName
    $Net             = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $ComputerName |
                       Where-Object {$_.IPConnectionMetric -ne $null}
    # DNS - *** want to fix this so it breaks to one address per line.
    $DNSstring       = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName . |
                       Where-Object {$_.IPConnectionMetric -ne $null} |
                       Select-Object -ExpandProperty DNSServerSearchOrder
    $Disk            = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $ComputerName |
                       Where-Object DeviceID -eq "c:"

    # Prepare Output
    $NetInfo = [ordered]@{
        "Computer Name. . ." = $Net.PSComputerName
        "Link Speed . . . ." = (Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object status -eq "up" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LinkSpeed)
        "MAC. . . . . . . ." = $Net.MacAddress
        "IP Address . . . ." = ($Net.IPAddress.trim("{}"))
        "Default Gateway. ." = ($Net.DefaultIPGateway.trim("{}"))
        "DHCP Server. . . ." = $Net.DHCPServer
        "DNS Servers. . . ." = $DNSstring.Split(',')
        "Domain . . . . . ." = $Net.DNSDomain
    }
    $CompInfo = [ordered]@{
        "Manufacturer . . ." = $ComputerSystem.Manufacturer
        "Model. . . . . . ." = $ComputerSystem.Model
        "Service Tag. . . ." = $Bios.SerialNumber
        "OS. . . . .  . . ." = $OperatingSystem.Caption
        "OS Build . . . . ." = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\" | Select-Object -expandproperty ReleaseId)
        "OS Version . . . ." = $OperatingSystem.Version
    }

    # Output Information
    New-Object -TypeName PSobject -Property $NetInfo
    New-Object -TypeName PSobject -Property $CompInfo
    Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $ComputerName -Class Win32_LogicalDisk |
        Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3} |
        Select-Object @{Name="Disk Letter. . . .";Expression={($_.Name)}},
            @{Name="Disk Size (GB) . .";Expression={([Math]::Round($_.size/1gb))}},
            @{Name="Free Space (GB). .";Expression={([Math]::Round($_.freespace/1gb))}}
}

New-Item -Path alias:gcinf -Value Get-CompInf >$null 2>&1
```

No matter what the DNS search order outputs as follows

```
DNS Servers. . . . : {203.1.64.1, 134.148.24.3, 134.148.24.1, 157.85.116.16}
```

If I take the line separately

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName . |
    Where-Object {$_.IPConnectionMetric -ne $null} |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty DNSServerSearchOrder
```

I get the following output.

```
203.1.64.1
134.148.24.3
134.148.24.1
157.85.116.16
```

How can I get my function to show

```
DNS Servers. . . . : 203.1.64.1
                     134.148.24.3
                     134.148.24.1
                     157.85.116.16
```

Comment: `$DNSstring.Split(',')` -> ``$DNSstring -join "`n"``. Your variable is an array, not a single string, so there's nothing to split in the first place.

Comment: Beautiful, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ansgar Wiechers states the following code fixes it.

Replace `$DNSstring.Split(',')`
with
`` $DNSstring -join "`n" ``

Gives exact output required.